# Бот-автоответчик ВКонтакте с привязкой к Gmail

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, gmail

Возможно ли настроить автоответчик в беседе в ВКонтакте, чтобы участники беседы могли написать кодовое слово (например "нужен код") и автоответчик мог пересылать в беседу последнее письмо из моего gmail?

Нужно это тогда, когда кто-то пытается зайти в мой гугл аккаунт и Гугл требует подтверждение личности, он мог выбрать "отправить проверочный код по письму", затем пишет в беседу "нужен код", и бот пересылает ему содержимое последнего письма из gmail.

Возможно ли такое реализовать?

Если невозможно с gmail, то хотя бы как сделать так, чтобы после написания кодового слова в беседу бот мог выдавать определенный ответ (например на кодовое слово "нужен код" бот отвечал "12345").

Comment: `Возможно ли такое реализовать?` Теоретически да. Бот слушает сообщения в беседе, видит команду, по почтовому протоколу открывает ящик и отправляет нужное сообщение.